# get children from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure

```
root
    -sections
        -section1
            -student1
                -GPA
                -lastname
            -student2
                -GPA
                -lastname
        -section2
            -student1
                -GPA
                -lastname
```

I need to get **GPA** of the student desired by the user.

I am doing this:

```
String student = student.getText().toString(); //Student1/Student2 entered
String section = section.getText().toString();
    //This is Section1, Student1, say (obtained from EditText)...
```

Then I am doing

```
myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sections");
myref1 = myref.child(section).child(student).child("GPA");
myref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String gpa = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
  }
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

I am getting 0.0 as the result.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's probably that the value of GPA for the student on the section is 0.0. Have you debug your application and see why it print the current result?

Comment: Yes, I have printed the value in the LOG and a textView (just in case). That's how I know the value is 0.0

Comment: What is the GPA of the student in that section in firebase database before it printed out as 0.0 on the application?

Comment: It is a value between 3 and 4 (Eg: 3.1, 3.75, 4.0 etc)

Comment: Maybe you need to include more code in your question. From what I have seen it, your code seems fine.

Comment: @evan: as you can see we're having a hard time figuring out what's wrong from the code you shared. Can you try with hard-coded values for `student` and `section`? If you also have the problem with that, please update the code in your question to reflect this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I don't have a problem with a hard coded value. I don't have a problem with taking the input either since I am using the same variables in another part of the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Normally users need to authenticate before they can read or write in the database. Did you disable the rules in the console or was some user logged in?

You can see the rules tab in this picture: https://www.novoda.com/blog/content/images/2016/06/Screenshot_20160621_174302.png

**EDIT**

The code seems to be fine, maybe there is somthing wrong with the keys "section" and "student". You can test it by using hard coded strings.

Comment: @janik: That was my first thought too. But if the user has no permission, the `onDataChange` won't be called.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: The code seems to be fine, maybe there is somthing wrong with the keys "section" and "student". You can test it by using hard coded strings